"Что ли" всегда обособляется или нет? Какая это часть речи?
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
С одной стороны, данная тема кажется несложной, но в то же время вопросы по правописанию и определению  сочетания ЧТО ЛИ все же возникают. Это частица или вводное слово? Всегда ли нужно обособлять ЧТО ЛИ или допускаются исключения?

Источники

Русский орфографический словарь: что ли (ль), вводн. сл.
Справочник
ЧТО ЛИ, частица. Обособляется.
Что вы, отцы святые, белены объелись, что ли? М. Булгаков, Бег. Он прожил с ней, что ли, три или четыре года... М. Зощенко, Психологическая история. Вспомнить, что ли, юность, ту, что пролетела? С. Есенин, Сыпь, тальянка...
Карта слов  – Как это расхотелось? – возмутилась она в ответ. – Зря что ли столько стараний?! В приведенных примерах из современной литературы вообще обособления нет.

Правила

В Сети есть информация о том, что частица не обособляется только  в начале предложения. Как объяснить такое решение?

Sharon, Карта слов учитывает и знаки, поэтому в ней есть всё. Набираем с запятыми, и появятся примеры с обособлением что ли. И там отдельно представлены наши классики.

Я набрала "что ли"  безо всяких дополнений.  Но в любом случае в этих примерах запятых не было. Правила изменились или что? // Хорошо, я рада за классиков.  А что у нас с современным письмом?

Это я увидел, поэтому и говорю, что Карта собирает всё. И в современной литературе тоже есть обособление "что ли". По Карте слов невозможно понять, как пишут чаще, так как там поровну представлены парные варианты почти по всем спорным темам.

Я знаю, что собирает (по другим тема).  Но здесь вот что интересно. В карте подобраны примеры, где вроде бы и не хочется ставить эти запятые. Может, пора разобраться, частица это или вводное слово. А то графика получается неясная. В общем, я считаю, что там должно быть два варианта. // Но это другой вопрос, а пока остается то, о чем спросила. Ну и комментарий можно дать по отсутствию обособления во многих примерах.

"Частица «что ли» обладает свойствами вводного слова, поэтому чаще всего обособляется". И такую двойственность в плане частей речи имеют многие слова. Согласен, что далеко не всегда хочется обособлять. Думаю, что лингвисты не смогут прийти к единому мнению, пусть только официальная Грамота не будет столь категорична...

Словарь РАН называет частицу вводным словом, вы умеете  различать эти названия?  Почему вы назвали слово именно частицей? //
Здесь есть одна фишка, которая важна, поэтому мне хотелось бы однозначно определить часть речи. //  Ну и в начале предложения будете обособлять "что ли"? Это принципиальный вопрос, который меня  с самого начала заинтересовал.  // У нас любят не приходить к единому мнению, конформизм удобен.  А вот попробуйте отличить один вариант от другого, здесь нужно хорошее с чувство языка)

Я не называл, у меня в кавычках. // Однозначность определяете вы сами, так как это "амбивалентные" слова. //  "Что ли(,) на работу поехать?" – так я не напишу и не скажу. "Может, на работу поехать?" Количество слогов, ударение, интонация совпадают в этих вариантах. Но вот после "может" мы договорились ставить запятую...

О, вот нашёл здесь, у нас: "Употребление частицы что ли в начале предложения возможно в просторечии: Что ли к дежурному вас отвести?; Что ли нам чайку попить?"

Я его вижу)  Так будем обособлять?

Мне всё равно :)) Я так не стану писать. А автор пусть сам решает.

Всё уже отвечено :))

А по-моему еще и не начато))   (1) Отсутствие запятой в начале предложения нужно и можно объяснить. (2) Есть один случай, когда обособления нет по правилам.

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
ЧАСТЬ 1. ЧАСТИЦА ЧТО ЛИ ПО ПРАВИЛАМ
ОПРЕДЕЛЕНИЕ
ЧТО ЛИ — это модально-вопросительная частица, состоящая из вопросительного местоимения ЧТО и частицы ЛИ.  Она выражает сомнение, неуверенность или удивление, а также запрашивает подтверждение. Иногда это выражение нужно для высказывания предположения.
ПРАВИЛА

Частица ЧТО ЛИ обособляется в большинстве случаев

В середине предложения:
 Я взглянул на часы. Домой, что ли, уйти? 
 — Ах он разбойник! смеяться, что ли, приехал над нами? 
 Лермонтов М. Ю., Герой нашего времени, 1840 

В конце предложения:
 Всем говорит любезности, подносит конфеты, букеты: он 
 развит, что ли? Гончаров И. А., Обрыв, 1869 

 О чем? о Чацком, что ли? Чего сомнительно? Я первый, я 
 открыл! Давно дивлюсь я, как никто его не свяжет! Грибоедов 
 А. С., Горе от ума, 1824 


В начале предложения частица ЧТО ЛИ  не обособляется (разговорная речь):
 Что ли мне чайку попить (разг. речь) (колебание). 
 Пример из АГ-80.
 *Что ли уши у вас золотом завешаны, не слышите ничего.*


Если частица ЧТО ЛИ относится к обособленному обороту, то она входит в его состав и обособляется вместе с ним по правилам для вводных слов: В дверь позвонили какие-то люди, рекламщики что ли». Сравнить: В дверь позвонили какие-то рекламщики, что ли».


Розенталь  § 25, пункт 4. Вводные слова и словосочетания
4. Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце 
обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, 
присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно 
не отделяется: Среди товарищей есть эдакие поэты, лирики что 
ли, проповедники любви к людям (М. Г.)

ЧАСТЬ 2. ЧАСТИЦА ЧТО ЛИ. АВТОРСКАЯ ПУНКТУАЦИЯ
Чем объясняется обособление частицы ЧТО ЛИ в большинстве случаев по образцу вводных слов? Рассмотрим вариант, когда в начале предложения частица не обособляется: Что ли опять опоздал? Сравним: Что, опять опоздал? Произношение именно такое, без паузы в первом случае  и с паузой во втором, причем решение однозначное.
Получается, что постановка запятой определяется  фонетикой. Тогда можно предположить, что в некоторых случаях возможны варианты как в записи предложения, так и в его произношении. В этом случае автор может выбрать нужный смысл: частица или вводное слово. Отметим, что при этом изменится расстановка ударений в предложении, что важно учитывать.
Вот примеры из современной литературы без обособления частицы ЧТО ЛИ: Зря что ли столько стараний?! Совсем что ли с ума сошёл? И др.
Сравним варианты:  ЗрЯ что ли / столько стараний?  Зря, / что ли, / столько старАний?
Возможно такое произношение: в первом случае частица относится к слову зря и выделяется ударением, а во втором ударение уходит в конец фразы.
Таким образом,  в современном правописании допускается вариант без обособления частицы, когда отсутствует значение вводности.  Вводное слово выражает отношение говорящего к сказанному, в то время как частица подчеркивает вопросительный характер слова. Но пока такое письмо не нормировано и является авторским.
Карта слов
ИСТОЧНИКИ ПО ТЕМЕ

ПАС под ред. Лопатина § 111

Вопросительно-восклицательные слова (частицы или их сочетания) что, что ли, ну как, что же, как же, ну, а, да ну, надо же выделяются запятыми внутри предложения или отделяются запятой, если стоят в начале предложения: — Сыночек, что, шибко он его зашиб-то? (Шукш.); — Что, хороша? — громко крикнула охрипшим голосом Маргарита Николаевна (Булг.);
Если вопросительно-восклицательные слова стоят в конце предложения, то перед ними ставится запятая, а после них соответствующий знак — вопросительный или восклицательный: — Обогнать, что ли? — спросил шофер (Шукш.);
В словаре РАН указана вводная функция частицы ЧТО ЛИ. В этом случае частица должна обособляться, что и делается в большинстве случаев. В устной речи частица выделяется паузами.

АГ-80 о частице ЧТО ЛИ

§ 1693. К вопросительным частицам относятся частицы а, ли (ль), не ... ли, неужели, никак (прост.), ужели (устар.), разве, что за, что, что ли, как. Все эти частицы совмещают значение вопросительности с более или менее ярко выраженной модальной окрашенностью.
Частицы что, что ли, а, как относятся к разговорной, непринужденной речи. Частица что или открывает собою вопросительное предложение, или следует за вынесенным в начало предложения именем: Что, он опять опаздывает?; Он что, опять опаздывает? Частица что выражает также переспрос ( - Ты меня слышишь? - Что?). Частица что ли, вносящая оттенок фамильярности, обычно заключает собою предложение (Заснул что ли?; Опять скандал, что ли?), но может и открывать его. Эта частица очень часто употребляется вместе с частицей что; они обрамляют предложение (Что, заснул, что ли?; Что, опять скандал, что ли?).
§ 1695. Модальные частицы вносят в предложение разные значения субъективного отношения к сообщаемому: Что ли мне чайку попить (разг. речь) (колебание);
Грамматическая справка
Частицы относятся к служебным частям речи. Они придают различные дополнительные смысловые значения как словам, так и предложению в целом. Модальные частицы выражают отношение к действительности.
Вводные слова – это различные части речи, употребленные в особой синтаксической функции. Они не являются членами предложения и не имеют грамматических связей с другими словами. Для них указывается только значение.
